# Nonparametric estimation in diffusion

Tags: st.statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

[Fan and Wang](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/08/SpotVol2.pdf)

In the above paper, the Authors provide estimators for the squared spot volatility process $\left(\sigma^{2}_{t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$.
My question is how to find estimators for the process itself? So I want to estimate the process $\left(\sigma_{t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on high frequency data, it is not possible to estimate the process $\left(\sigma_{t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$. More precisely, there is no way to estimate the sign of it. Note that, if $W_{t}$ is a standard BM, then $-W_{t}$ is also a standard BM.